# firebase create firestore database stuck

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

when creating database and then choosing location, after that I select start in test mode but it stucks in endless loop and in console there are many warnings and errors:

[image]

Thanks in advance...

I tried in different browsers but again it's not working.

Comment: If you're having problems with the Firebase console, reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) directly.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Check the developer console of your browser for relevant error messages. If that doesn't show anything or doesn't help you figure it out, then as Doug said: [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: fyi: I can reproduce and am filing an issue with the team as we speak...

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

I can reproduce this issue, and paged the on-call engineers.

Meanwhile: if I reload the page, and ignore the warning about unsaved changes, it seems that the database has been correctly created. That might be a workaround until the UI issue is fixed.